# MySQL Selecting A Key From A Seperate Table

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently fetching data from a group of location MySQL tables here is what I currently have

```
$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode, Population FROM City WHERE (Population > '6000000') ORDER BY Population DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";

        echo "<td>$row[0]</td>";
        echo "<td>$row[1]</td>";
        echo "<td>$row[2]</td>";

        echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysql_close($link);
```

The thing I am trying to figure out is how to convert the CountryCode to the actual country. Here is how I would call the country table to get the name

```
SELECT Name FROM Country WHERE Code = 'CountryCode';
```

How would I combine these two statements into one?

EDIT: Here is what I got to work. Is this considered a JOIN?

```
$query = "SELECT a.Name, a.CountryCode, a.Population, b.Code, b.Name FROM City a, Country b WHERE (a.CountryCode = b.Code) AND (a.Population > '6000000') ORDER BY Population DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";

        echo "<td>$row[0]</td>";
        echo "<td>$row[2]</td>";
        echo "<td>$row[4]</td>";

        echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysql_close($link);
```

Comment: You need to learn about `JOIN`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Comment: Is the way I did it the best way?

Comment: What you did is clear and straightforward (within SQL).  It is also efficient enough that "best" is more a judgement of readability.  I would suggest names more meaningful than "a" and "b", but the rest of this is fine.

Answer (score 0):

U need to join City table and Country table having one primary key and one foreign key.

Read about Natural Join. It's easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
$query = "SELECT city.Name,country.Name,city.CountryCode,city.Population from city INNER JOIN country where country.CountryCode=city.CountryCode and city.population>5000 ORDER BY city.Population DESC";
```

This is working fine.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can use `CTRL+K` to format your code and make more readable